# Creating a simple pie chart using dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to create a number of interactive pie charts using dc.js to represent a basketball team's stats. One pie chart would have each player's points, another their salary, etc., represented as a portion of the team's total.

I don't really understand how to use the crossfilter [.dimension()](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension) and [.group()](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_group) functions. And does reduceSum() really need to be in there? All I'm getting is an empty pie chart. Other examples I've seen have differenty structured data and don't apply to this situation.

Here is a bit of the relevant code for a salary pie chart:

```
var data = [
{"player":"boomhauer", "rebound_avg":12.1, "salary":4000, "point_avg":15},
{"player":"bill", "rebound_avg":4.2, "salary":3000, "point_avg":20},
{"player":"hank", "rebound_avg":12.1, "salary":4000, "point_avg":15},
{"player":"dale", "rebound_avg":16.1, "salary":6000, "point_avg":4},
];

var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var playerDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.player;});  

var salaryPerPlayer = playerDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.salary;});

var salaryGroupPerPlayer = salaryPerPlayer.group(function(d) {return d.player; });

var salaryRingChart = dc.pieChart("#chart-ring-salary");

salaryRingChart
        .width(200)
        .height(200)
        .slicesCap(17)
        .innerRadius(10)
        .dimension(salaryPerPlayer)
        .group(salaryGroupPerPlayer)
        .renderLabel(true);


dc.renderAll();
```

All I'm getting is an empty pie chart.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think just lose the `salaryGroupPerPlayer`:

```
var data = [
{"player":"boomhauer", "rebound_avg":12.1, "salary":4000, "point_avg":15},
{"player":"bill", "rebound_avg":4.2, "salary":3000, "point_avg":20},
{"player":"hank", "rebound_avg":12.1, "salary":4000, "point_avg":15},
{"player":"dale", "rebound_avg":16.1, "salary":6000, "point_avg":4},
];

var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var playerDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.player;});  

var salaryPerPlayer = playerDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.salary;});

var salaryRingChart = dc.pieChart("#chart-ring-salary");

salaryRingChart
        .width(200)
        .height(200)
        .slicesCap(17)
        .innerRadius(10)
        .dimension(salaryPerPlayer)
        .group(salaryPerPlayer)
        .renderLabel(true);


dc.renderAll();
```

Here's a good Crossfilter tutorial: http://blog.rusty.io/2012/09/17/crossfilter-tutorial/

The reduceSum is necessary because the default aggregation on a group in Crossfilter is a count. This would just count the number of records for each player, which is 1. So, not very interesting!

I would question why you are using Crossfilter at all though. The data is all pre-aggregated and you are only going to have 1 dimension (player). Filtering on these charts won't really make sense. Crossfilter is designed more for scenarios in which you have dis-aggregated data (maybe 1 record for each player in each game, o even play-by-play data) and you want to aggregate the data and filter dynamically on different dimensions.

Comment: Thanks! You're right-- I think I don't need crossfilter for this kind of data set. I like the piegraphs in dc.js, so maybe I'll find a way to create them without using crossfilter.

Getting rid of salaryGroupPerPlayer still leaves me with an empty piechart. I think I'll have to really wrap my head around crossfilter, dc.js, and mapreduce before taking another stab at this. Thanks for the tutorial, I'll go through it.

Comment: dc.js just expects objects with some specific properties/functions that supply the data to be passed to its dimension() and group() methods. IIRC, dimension objects need `filter`, `filterExact`, `filterRange`, and `filterFunction` methods, while group objects need an `all` method (or sometimes `top`). If you just pass them empty objects and then consult the error console, it will tell you which method is missing. Good luck!

Comment: I don't think there is much harm in using crossfilter when it's not needed. It might be a little slower but you probably won't notice it. Most of the cost of visualization is DOM elements not calculations. So, maybe easier to use it until you have a reason not to.

Comment: I see your point. But are there any structural issues you see with the code? It's still outputting an empty pie chart. It's creating a visualization, so we must be on the right track.

Comment: @user5279393 I'd agree with Gordon that using Crossfilter won't hurt. Though its API and stateful-ness can be confusing on its own. Regarding your visualization - I can't see anything specifically wrong. Can you create a jsFiddle please and show us the problem?

Comment: @EthanJewett I made a jsFiddle, and the code ran as intended, to my surprise. There must be a mistake on the version on my machine. 

http://jsfiddle.net/vasadourian/bor0g2a8/

Comment: I found the mistake. If you look at line 11 of the js code, I had `+d.salary` . Once I removed the + it worked. I remember seeing that operator used in an example. Not sure what purpose it serves.

Comment: The + just casts to a number (or NaN). It makes it more likely that the dimension is naturally ordered by dealing with the error condition of an empty string by converting it to 0. It looks to me like your example works with and without the + in Safari. Haven't tested in other browsers though. Very interesting!